# Moved values when multiplying numbers

Tags: rust

I'm trying to use the following code:

```
fn get_max(string:Vec<BigUint>) -> BigUint {
    let mut max:BigUint = num::zero();

    for i in 0..(string.len()-13) {
        let mut prod:BigUint = num::one();
        for j in i..(i+13) {
            prod.mul(&string[j]);
        }

        if prod.clone().gt(&max) {
            max = prod;
        }
    }

    max
}
```

But I get the following error when I try to compile:

```
src/main.rs:13:4: 13:8 error: use of moved value: `prod`
src/main.rs:13          prod.mul(&string[j]);
                        ^~~~
note: `prod` was previously moved here because it has type `num::bigint::BigUint`, which is non-copyable
src/main.rs:16:6: 16:10 error: use of moved value: `prod`
src/main.rs:16      if prod.clone().gt(&max) {
                       ^~~~
src/main.rs:13:4: 13:8 note: `prod` moved here because it has type `num::bigint::BigUint`, which is non-copyable
src/main.rs:13          prod.mul(&string[j]);
                        ^~~~
src/main.rs:17:10: 17:14 error: use of moved value: `prod`
src/main.rs:17          max = prod;
                              ^~~~
src/main.rs:13:4: 13:8 note: `prod` moved here because it has type `num::bigint::BigUint`, which is non-copyable
src/main.rs:13          prod.mul(&string[j]);
                        ^~~~
error: aborting due to 3 previous errors
```

As far as I can tell, I'm never moving `prod`, so what is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`prod.mul` is the multiplication method from the `Mul` trait, which takes two values (the two operands) and returns another one (the result). In this case, it is taking `prod` by value, and so `prod` is being consumed, moved into the method call.

You meant `prod = prod.mul(&string[j]);`, which can be better written using the `*` operator instead of calling the `mul` method: `prod = prod * &string[j];` (sorry, `prod *= &string[j]` doesn’t work yet).

Comment: Thanks! I tried *= first but didn't realize that only * works. Nice to know that!

Comment: The most recent discussion about getting `*=` working generally is at https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/953